# Dynamically show values on text box change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to display some values on text box change.for a example

if item "A" = $25 and if the customer order 5 of "A" item when text box change to 5 a label or a text box should show $125. How do i do it using javascript and php or just using javascript.

```
<input type='text' id='item' value=""/>
```

total should show in

```
<input type='text' id='tot' value=""/>
```

if anyone can give me a hint how to do this it will be most appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking of something like this

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='item' value="" data-price="25" />
<span></span>
```

JS

```
$("#item").keyup(function()
{
    var value = $(this).val() * $(this).data("price");
    $("span").text("$" + value);
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/6KeFU/

I'm using `data` to store the price associated with the item

Comment: thank you. how about if i give price like this. if more then 100 it will be 25 and if more 200 it will be 15.

Comment: thanks it works except for the 200 plus it gives a wrong value

Comment: yeah, I'm sorry. the cases inside the switch are in reverse order. you should put the greater case first!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery it can be done like this, assuming order value is entered in item input field and 25$ per item is hardcoded.

```
$("#item").on('change',function(){
  $("#tot").val($(this).val() * 25);
})
```